# MongoDB Retrieve single value from array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Assuming that if i have such document

**{ "id":"1", "references":["AD1","AD2","AD3"] }**

I would like to retrieve single value ("AD1") within the array. is there anyway that i can do that with mongodb query? i have use various way but that it would instead return me the whole array instead of individual single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) and [`$filter`](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      references: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$references",
          as: "ref",
          cond: { $eq: [ "AD1", "$$ref" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can see it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H28f9dFX7Dv)

Note however that `$filter` is available in mongoDB 3.2 version and higher

Comment: Hi @Akrion , thanks for the reply. I have one more question though , assuming that the document above is of parent document , i do have the following child document Child Document

{ "id":"AD1",  "group":"A"}

{ "id":"AD2",  "group":"B"}

{ "id":"AD3", "group":"C"} , how do i link it to do mongo CRUD query assuming that they are releated by the references id

Comment: Can you please update your question if it does not represent what the actual problem is?

Comment: If you have another one just post another question since the comments become questions and it gets hard to follow etc.

Comment: Hi @Akrion , noted with thanks! I actually posted similar question few week ago on stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441709/mongodb-parent-child-reference-document?noredirect=1#comment93756946_53441709) but still couldn't find answer to it , appreciate if u would take a look on how i would do CRUD mongodb query under such parent-child schema

Comment: Yeah this is a separate question. You can close/accept this one if it does what you need and for the other one it was closed since it was a `dub` for using `$lookup`. Just read/practice how to use the `$lookup` pipeline which does `join` one `table`/collection with another in your case `parent/children` by id.